# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser javascript excel export not working

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wpf, excel

I have implemented my web application using angular and javascript and a window application using wpf. I tried to call export function from wpf application to the browser embedded, it is not working, it does not show any error. But it works in all other browsers like chrome, mozilla, internet explorer. Help me for any clue.Thanks.

Comment: The question is not exactly clear. Are you saying you have a CefSharp control inside a WPF application and your call from C# into the javascript of your page is not working? Could be lots of reasons. Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi Fallenidol, Right. I tried using like this to test "<cs:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Address="D:\sampleDataTransform\sampleDataTransform\index.html"/>" I can see the browser but upon calling excel export function, nothing happens. The same URL in other browser, an excel file is downloaded and stored.

Comment: Sounds like it might possibly be a permissions thing or not able to call out to a the excel file or something. It might be an idea to start commenting things out and start small and incrementally add functionality back to your index.html until you can pinpoint the line or call that is failing inside CefSharp.

Comment: My suspect is that ChromiumWebBrowser itself has an issue with exporting. The problem is it cannot be trace back to see error in IDE since it happens in browser. To debug in browser as well, cannot use develper tool or F12 like in chrome and mozilla to know the root cause.

Comment: That export function will result in excel file generated and downloaded? If so - check if other downloads are working (open any site where you can click on link to download file and see if it works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The reason is because the download handler is not added. We need to add manually in coding for that so that whatever we are downloading or saving to PC, we can see the download popup. It's simple, just a line only.

```
webBrowser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,you need define a class such as DownloadHandler,then inherit IDownloadHandler interface.

```
public class DownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
{
    public void OnBeforeDownload(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
    {
        if (!callback.IsDisposed)
        {
            using (callback)
            {
                callback.Continue(@"C:\Users\" +
                        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name +
                        @"\Downloads\" +
                        downloadItem.SuggestedFileName,
                    showDialog: true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnDownloadUpdated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Secondly,before the browser is initialized create a DownloadHandler object like this:

```
browser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();
```